# Collapse dataframe in r by factor with NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to collapse my dataframe so that there's only one factor variable per row and the values all collapse on themselves to one row each. Here's an example:

```
mat <- data.frame(type = c(rep("int",5), rep("num",5)), diag(sample.int(9,6), 10))
mat[mat == 0] <- NA
mat[5,11] <- 4
```

Now I want this to be:

> type, X1, ..., X8, X9, X10
>
> int, 2, 7, ...,NA, NA, 4
>
> num, NA, NA, ..., 3, 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `type`, then use `summarize_all` with `na.omit`:

```
mat %>% group_by(type) %>% summarise_all(funs(na.omit(.)[1]))

# A tibble: 2 x 11
#    type    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10
#  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    int     8     3     7     6     4    NA    NA    NA    NA     4
#2    num    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     9     8     3     7     6
```